# Хочу скачать npm pkg-config, но получаю ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, visual-studio-code

```
PS D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new> npm i pkg-config
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || npm run build-release
npm ERR! > better-sqlite3@7.6.2 build-release
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild --release
npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=17.7.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.7.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.6 found at "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.30907.101) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:364:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\WinUsers\User\Desktop\eco new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
```

Я использую самую новую visual studio code 2022, как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Установите C++ для разработки. Скачиваете установщик Visual Studio(не Code),  в установщике ищете "Desktop development with C++" и устанавливаете. После этой процедуры пакет должен установиться нормально.